# xts object to ts object / seasonal dummies for xts

Tags: r, time-series

I am trying to use a function from the [forecast](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/forecast/index.html) package, `seasonaldummy()`, which requires a time series object as input, but I have an [xts](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/xts/index.html) object, call it `x`. So first, is it correct that [xts](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/xts/index.html) objects can not be directly passed to functions that require a `ts` object?

I then tried to coerce it to a `ts` object. I tried this by `as.ts(x)`. The function still produces an error.

I looked at the [xts](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/xts/index.html) vignette, and in particular the `reclass` function, but all I could understand from that was how to coerce non xts objects to xts. It appears I have to do the opposite, and that `as.ts(x)` does not work.

I have put a MWE below, where the last two lines generate an error.

```
> a = rnorm(20)    
> dt = seq(as.POSIXct("2010-03-24"),by="days",len=20)
> library(xts)   
> a = xts(a,dt)   
> library(forecast)   
> seasonaldummy(a)

Error in seasonaldummy(a) : Not a time series

> seasonaldummy(as.ts(a))

Error in seasonaldummy(as.ts(a)) : subscript out of bounds
```

Answer (score 5):

To use seasonal dummy variables, the period of seasonality must be an integer. When you convert a to a time series using `as.ts(a)`, the period is set to 1/86400 (seconds in a day). So if you want to use seasonal dummy variables you will have to specify what the most appropriate period is first. For example, if you want to use a day-of-week seasonality, use

```
seasonaldummy(ts(a,f=7))
```

Comment: How to convert from xts to ts if my original xts doesn't have exactly the same number of data per cycle?
For instance if I have daily data every weekday => every year there is not the same number of daily data... is there a best practice around that?